# C# converting from object

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` which is filled with `Lists` each list represents a `Datacolumn` in my `Datatable`. I am trying to iterate through a specific list in the dictionary but i get an error when trying to append i, stating I cannot convert from object to double.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<object>>> dict;
```

I add to the dictionary by;

```
dict = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[c]).ToList());
```

Where the error happens;

```
XyDataSeries<double,double> xyseries;

private void chkbx1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var list = dict["ColumnName1"];

    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        Convert.ToDouble(i);
        xyseries.Append(one++, i);
    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure your data contains only `double` types? Is it possible it contains a null value?

Comment: Convert.ToDouble *returns* the converted double, it doesn't change `i` in place

Comment: what are you converting to double `Convert.ToDouble(i);` this does nothing you need to assign  some variable = Convert.ToDouble(i);` and `i` is not a good var name is your case.. horrible naming convention

Comment: The name `i` suggests an `int`. `obj` would be a better name for an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here: `Convert.ToDouble(i);`

`ToDouble` returns a `double`, it doesn't change `i` into a double. You need to do the following:

```
foreach (var i in list)
{
    var d = Convert.ToDouble(i);
    xyseries.Append(one++, d);
}
```